# Update UI while method is executing in main thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading

I have a method that takes 30 seconds to run and updates a gridview after the 30 seconds is up. After 10 seconds, it receives the first item in the grid. Also, after 20, the second item and after the 30 seconds, the final item is received.

I want the grid to be updated every 10 seconds in the UI. Is this possible and how can it be done.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Look into the class `BackgroundWorkerThread`. There are plenty of questions here on Stack Overflow already about this.

Comment: Also look at Tasks. Easy to use and less headache of thread management.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [TImer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) control that would fire an event after whatever time you set to its `Interval` property. In that `event handler`, you could call your method or do whatever you want.